# Dynamically changed value of text box should have to be changed on radio button click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes and respective radio buttons associated with it.The value of the  first text boxe are retrieved from database and all calculation are being done on the database value.But if i want to change the first text box value manually the next 2 boxes values must have to changed.And i dnt want to insert this manually entered value into database.can u tell me how to perform calculation on the manually inserted value into textbox.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes; ...can you tell us what calculation(s) you want to perform, and give an example of a value and the expected output/changed values? Also, you don't have any 'text boxes,' you might have three `<input type="text" />` or `<textarea>` elements, or a mix of those.

Comment: if you don't add the manually entered value to database , what are you going to do with it

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript and onchange event on textbox.

add event to textbox properties:

```
onChange="calculate();"
```

write a javascript function:

```
function calculate(){
    var calculatedValue = textbox1.value;
    //calculate
   textbox2.value = calculatedValue; 
}
```

I didn't check it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox1').change(function(){

     var value = $(this).val();

     var value2 = function1(value);
     var value3 = function2(value);

    $('#textbox2').val(value2);
    $('#textbox3').val(value3);

});

function function1(){
    //do calculation 
}

function function2(){
    //do calculation 
}
```